# bash: how to combine cd and ./?

Tags: bash, executable

Lets say I have a folder called `xfile`, inside of it we have `runthis` which is executable.
So, in order to execute that, I have to `cd xfile` and then `./runthis`. and it will work just fine.
But, If I have a script call it `run.sh` and do this `./xfile/runthis`, it will says `run.sh: line xx: ./xfile/runthis: No such file or directory`

So, how to make it happend without doing `cd`? It's been bugging me alot lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading dot in your command `./runthis` means "relative to the current directory". But when you want to call it from outside the directory, remove the dot and provide the absolute path of your executable file `xfile/runthis`. The same is true when you want to call it from your `run.sh`

Comment: yeah, I just realized it too minute ago, the absolute path for me would be something like `/home/username/xfile/runthis`

Comment: For future study, you also have the PATH variable mechanism into which you set the list of directories where are located your commands. Then you can call the command without any leading pathname as the shell will search it into the directories located in the PATH list : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path